# PWA does not show notification, even after it's enabled from Android chrome browser

Tags: progressive-web-apps

We've PWA where user **has not allowed notification** to be shown first time ( when website is opened first time and notification dialog is shown ).

But user has **installed PWA to mobile home screen**.

Later user opens the website again and by **tapping on lock icon allows notification.**

Even after this, user doesn't get to see new notification.

Please clarify how to fix notification in this case.

Comment: Could be something stuck in the browser cache from when they said no the first time. You may need to ask them to clear their entire browser's cache. What browser? Mobile or desktop?

Comment: Android Chrome Browser, just to clarify is there a way to allow notification from PWA installed on home screen ? or each time user needs to goto browser itself and enable ?